# Sass build failing in React JS

Tags: css, sass, npm-scripts

I have following Sass script:

```
@import "../../../../global_css/variables/variables";
.heading .sectionAbout {
    padding: $padding-top-viewport 0;
    margin-top: calc(-1 * (#{top-viewport-height} - #{clip-background-height}));
    background: $color-grey-light-1;
}
```

When I try to run the build file in react using `yarn build` (`"build": "react-scripts build",`), I get an error:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text.
  Erroneous area:
1: -1 * (top-viewport-height - clip-background-height)
^........^
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined
```

My `node-sass` version is `"node-sass": "4.14.1"`. How do I get rid of this irritating error to proceed with my build?

Comment: '$' skipped before top-viewpost-height and clip-background-height variables. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include $ before your variable. I believe this is missed out for the two variables used inside calc function

Try

```
@import "../../../../global_css/variables/variables";
.heading .sectionAbout {
    padding: $padding-top-viewport 0;
    margin-top: calc(-1 * (#{$top-viewport-height} - #{$clip-background-height}));
    background: $color-grey-light-1;
}
```

Ref:- https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation